# Accessing MTP device from Windows 10 universal app

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, mtp

I have troubles accessing an MTP device (music player) from Windows 10 universal app.

I can get the device root folder, but I can only enumerate subfolders, StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync returns empty list.

I also cannot find way to find the device total and free memory.

Answer (score 0):

I have had mixed results with this. The factors I have encountered that have prevented traversing the device folders.

- The device itself. Works on some devices but not others.
- The USB controller matters (front ports on my pc don't usually work with this but back ports do)
- USB cable. Some work some don't

The frustrating part is none of this seems to be an issue when using windows explorer which means MTP is working just fine. Its an issue with Microsoft's StorageFolder implementation.